# Removing Special Characters in a Text File in R

Tags: r, regex, text-files, special-characters, gsub

I'm using a text file in R and using the readLine function and regexs to extract words from it. The file uses special characters around words (such as # sings before and after a word to show it is bolded or @ before and after a word to show it should be italicized) to indicate special meanings, which are messing up my regexs.

So far this is my r code which removed all empty lines and then combined my text file into a single vector :

```
    book<-readLines("/Users/Desktop/SAMPLE .txt",encoding="UTF-8")
    #remove all empty lines
    empty_lines = grepl('^\\s*$', book)
    book = book[! empty_lines]
    #combine book into one variable
    xBook = paste(book, collapse = '')
    #remove extra white spaces for a single text of the entire book
    updated<-trimws(gsub("\\s+"," ",xBook))
```

when i run updated, i see the entire file stored in the variable updated but with the special characters:

> updated
>   [1] "It is a truth universally acknowledged, that a #single# man in possession of a good fortune, must be in want of a wife. However little known the feelings or views of such a @man@ may be on his first entering a neighbourhood, this truth is so well fixed in the minds of the surrounding families, @that@ he is considered the rightful property of some one or other of #their# daughters.

**How can I remove all all the leading or trailing # or @ from the words in my updated variable?**

my desired output is just the plain text, with no indication of words that should be bolded or italicized:

> updated
>   [1] "It is a truth universally acknowledged, that a single man in possession of a good fortune, must be in want of a wife. However little known the feelings or views of such a man may be on his first entering a neighbourhood, this truth is so well fixed in the minds of the surrounding families, that he is considered the rightful property of some one or other of their daughters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gsub("[@#]([a-zA-Z]+)[@#]", "\\1", x)
```